# Symmetry axes of $f(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

What is the condition so that $ax+by+c=0$ is symmetry axe of $f(x)$ ? And how to find symmetry axes of $f(x)$?

I think we can solve by using the rotation matrix in linear algebra , but i'm very green at this field.